# How to prove 6ab=(a+b+c)(a+b) synthetically or without trilinear coordinates

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle with $AB=c, BC=a, CA=b$. Let I be the incenter and G be the centroid of ABC. Assume that $GI$ perpendicular to $CI$. Prove that $6ab=(a+b)(a+b+c)$.
I don't have any idea how to solve it.

The problem is the same as this one: [How to prove that $ 6ab=(a+b)(a+b+c)$ for triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593075/how-to-prove-that-6ab-ababc-for-triangle)

But I would like a synthetic proof without trilinear coordinates (meaning using only Euclid's axioms). I were triying many thing but I didn't prove it. I anyone has any idea please I don't want a full solution.

Thanks

Comment: A *synthetic* proof is where you start with known statements and build up towards your goal - but the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593075/how-to-prove-that-6ab-ababc-for-triangle) is synthetic. You should edit the old question, instead of repeating it again.

Comment: @DietrichBurde With synthetic proof I mean only euclid axioms. I don't see how to write that without trilinear coordinates