# Triangle with integer sides, and centroid-incenter $\perp$ incenter-C, what is the perimeter of triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

See the figure:

[image]

All the sides of $\triangle{ABC}$ are positive integers. The greatest common factor of $a$ and $b$ is $2$.
$G$ and $I$ are the centroid and incenter of the triangle. $GI \perp CI$. What is the perimeter of the triangle?

Comment: What are the upvotes for? Is it for posting a question that  doesn't seem easy to solve? (It has a straightforward approach given the right triangle). Please upvote posts that show efforts and OP's willingness to interact and contribute a discussion/topic to the site.

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning of upvoting a question...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593075/how-to-prove-that-6ab-ababc-for-triangle can help.

Comment: @rne Please read the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Tan Thank you! This is great reference. May I know how did you search a question on this site? is it possible to search existing questions?

Comment: @cosmo5 Thanks! Just updated the title

Comment: You can use https://approach0.xyz/search/. Not only for this site, you can use it for any kind of mathematical search.